# Tkinter: Problem with defining two cursor for the same database value showing in two different Treeview

Tags: python-3.x, function, tkinter, cursor

First problem:
In my Tkinter GUI I have two Treeviews which have the common database record "MASA". I define two get_cursor code (get_cursor1, get_cursor2) but "MASA" shows in only the FIRST TREEVIEW. What did I wrong? How can I fix?

Second problem:
self.rez_oda_var.set(row[0])
IndexError: string index out of range

'''

## ============FIRST TREEVIEW================

```
    list_Frame = Frame(rec_frame)

    self.rez_table = ttk.Treeview(list_Frame, selectmode="extended", columns=("MASA"), xscrollcommand = scroll_x.set, yscrollcommand = scroll_y.set)


    self.rez_table.heading("MASA", text="MASA", anchor="w")
    self.rez_table["show"] = "headings"
    self.rez_table.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    self.rez_table.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.get_cursor1)
    self.fetch_data()

    def get_cursor1(self, event):
    cursor_row = self.rez_table.focus()
    contents = self.rez_table.item(cursor_row)
    row = contents["values"]

    self.rez_masa_var.set(row[2])
```

## ============SECOND TREEVIEW=================

```
    masa_Frame = Frame(masa_frame)

    self.masa_table = ttk.Treeview(masa_Frame, selectmode="extended", columns=("MASA"), yscrollcommand = scroll_y.set)

    self.masa_table.heading("MASA", text="MASA", anchor="w")
    self.masa_table.column("MASA", width=40, minwidth=50)
    self.masa_table["show"] = "headings"
    self.masa_table.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    self.masa_table.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.get_cursor2)
    self.fetch_data()


    def get_cursor2(self, event):
    cursor_row = self.masa_table.focus()
    contents = self.masa_table.item(cursor_row)
    row = contents["values"]

    self.rez_masa_var.set(row[0])
```

## ============SELF.FETCH.DATA=================

```
    def fetch_data(self):
    con=pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", 
    database="kayıtlar")
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from reservation")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    if len(rows)!=0:
            self.rez_table.delete(*self.rez_table.get_children())
            for row in rows:
                    self.rez_table.insert("", END, values=row)
    con.commit()
    self.temizle()
    con.close()
```

'''

[LOOKS LIKE:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysXl0.jpg)

Comment: Can you please reduce this code to a [mcve]?

Comment: Please limit the question to asking about a single problem.

Comment: You better post the code of `self.fetch_data()` as well.

Comment: OK I edit it shorter

Comment: `self.fetch_data()` only update `self.rez_table`, but not `self.masa_table`.

Comment: Thanks I get the problem. But is there any other method without fetch_data code to get the same record in the second Treeview area?

Comment: You can save the result in a global list inside `fetch_data()` instead of updating `rez_table`.  Then use this global list to populate `rez_table` and `masa_table`.  Note that you should call `fetch_data()` once before creating the two treeviews.